# Bug in Array.IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, gethashcode

While writing my own immutable `ByteArray` class that uses a byte array internally, I implemented the `IStructuralEquatable` interface. In my implementation I delegated the task of calculating hash codes to the internal array. While testing it, to my great surprise, I found that my *two different arrays had the same structural hash code*, i.e. they returned the same value from [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988180.aspx). To reproduce:

```
IStructuralEquatable array11 = new int[] { 1, 1 };
IStructuralEquatable array12 = new int[] { 1, 2 };
IStructuralEquatable array22 = new int[] { 2, 2 };

var comparer = EqualityComparer<int>.Default;
Console.WriteLine(array11.GetHashCode(comparer));     // 32
Console.WriteLine(array12.GetHashCode(comparer));     // 32
Console.WriteLine(array22.GetHashCode(comparer));     // 64
```

`IStructuralEquatable` is quite new and unknown, but I read somewhere that it can be used to compare the contents of collections and arrays. Am I wrong, or is my .Net wrong?

Note that I am *not* talking about `Object.GetHashCode`!

Edit:
So, I am apparently wrong as unequal objects may have equal hash codes. But isn't `GetHashCode` returning a somewhat randomly distributed set of values a requirement? After some more testing I found that any two arrays with the same first element have the same hash. I still think this is strange behavior.

Comment: In addition to answers which point to duplicate hashcodes as is documented behavior, some reasoning and reflection would also lead you to the same conclusion. Consider that there are only ~4.2 billion different hashcodes. Can you create more than this many different objects of the type on which `GetHashCode` is called? In this case it is easy to see the answer is "yes". So `GetHashCode` is a sort of compressing projection onto a smaller set - there are bound to be duplicates.

Comment: What might also surprise you is that `Array.IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode` only uses the last 8 elements to compute the hash code.

Comment: Actually there is a bug.  See my edit.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk - while this might be true for a given version of .Net on a certain platform, I'm compelled to issue the standard warning not to rely on the values of hashcodes or how they are computed, since it is not guaranteed to be the same across updates or platforms.

Comment: @codekaizen Yes I will clarify that I am talking about MSFT .NET.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you have described is not a bug.  `GetHashCode()` does not guarantee unique hashes for nonequal objects.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx):

> If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object do not have to return different values.

**EDIT**

While the MSFT .NET implementation of `GetHashCode()` for `Array.IStructuralEquatable` obeys the principles in the above MSDN documentation, it appears that the authors *did not* implement it as intended.

Here is the code from "Array.cs":

```
    int IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comparer) { 
        if (comparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer"); 
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        int ret = 0;

        for (int i = (this.Length >= 8 ? this.Length - 8 : 0); i < this.Length; i++) {
            ret = CombineHashCodes(ret, comparer.GetHashCode(GetValue(0))); 
        } 

        return ret; 
    }
```

Notice in particular this line:

`ret = CombineHashCodes(ret, comparer.GetHashCode(GetValue(`**0**`)));`

Unless I am mistaken, that `0` was intended to be `i`.  Because of this, `GetHashCode()` always returns the same value for arrays with the same max(0, n-8th) element, where n is the length of the array. This isn't *wrong* (doesn't violate documentation), but it is clearly not as good as it would be if `0` were replaced with `i`. Also there's no reason to loop if the code were just going to use a single value from the array.

Comment: Agreed, looks like a bug. Consider filing a Connect issue? Is this .Net 4.0?

Comment: @codekaizen Yes, .NET 4.0.  I don't have .NET 4.5 on this machine. Care to check if it has been fixed in 4.5 (if you have VS 2012)?

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to write tests which compute the distribution of hashcodes for GetHashCode overrides.

Comment: Looks like the code is the same for any updates which 4.5 apply to the runtime.

Comment: Yep, it's already been filed, postponed, and removed from connect.  Here's the connect link:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529636

     and here is the cached copy: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BfWsi7JD3-wJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529636+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Postponed I'm used to, but removed? That's rare. WTF?!?

Comment: You plan on making a new issue? If so, let me know; I'll vote it up.

Comment: Yes I will file it tomorrow when I can repro on .NET 4.5.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14601/discussion-between-codekaizen-and-michael-graczyk)

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: Thanks for pointing out that my bug was removed from Connect. I filed the original issue, and received no notification that it was deleted. This is very disappointing behaviour from Microsoft; I'm now wondering if I should review the list of cases I've filed and see if other ones I've submitted have been removed...

Comment: @BradleyGrainger - my reaction would be to apply Hanlon's razor and chalk it up to a mistake. I had a popular SQL Server issue "disappear" a while back, but it turns out that it was just a permissions error they took years to correct, even after a good deal of followup by me.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: Good advice. Now that you mention it, I seem to remember that I had a bunch that were "lost" during some internal bug DB migration, but they all came back eventually.

Comment: I refiled the bug just in case.  You can find it here:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755995/system-array-istructuralequatable-gethashcode-does-not-compute-hash-codes-as-intended

Comment: I posted a followup on chat; I don't think it notifies by default.

Comment: bug still exists in 4.5.1.

Comment: I'm not sure this bug can be fixed now as it would lead to different hashes for the same values. Since hashes must remain the same no matter what we're probably stuck with this.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Hashes are not guaranteed to remain the same between versions of the framework, even for identical objects.  In fact, hashes are not even guaranteed to be the same across different instances of the .NET runtime.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Almost all days I end up with an unsolvable MS bug like this one :(

Answer (score 5):

This bug has been fixed, at least as of .NET 4.6.2. You can see it through [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,812).

```
ret = CombineHashCodes(ret, comparer.GetHashCode(GetValue(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetHashCode` does not return unique values for instances that are not equal. However, instances that are equal will always return the same hash code.

To quote from [`Object.GetHashCode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx):

> If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object do not have to return different values.

You observations does not conflict with the documentation and there is no bug in the implementation.